# Likes on official page on facebook in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to search approach to get like on official page on facebook in my native iOS app.

I read many questions and answers and the resume is no method for this in iOS SDK, but I found that facebook can open access for this method in API.

Where can I send my request for?

I'm sorry if I'm asking in wrong place. I don't know where I can ask.